# The stop button for my pomdoro clock does not function

Tags: javascript

I am building a pomodoro clock with start and stop button. I have the start button functioning, but not the stop button. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<h1> Pomodoro Clock</h1>
<!--Place holder for timer-->
<div id="timer" class="circle">Timer</div>
<!--//Start Button-->
<button onclick="setTimeout(timer, 1000);">Start</button>
<!--Stop Button-->
<button onclick="timer.stopTimer()">Stop</button>
```

JS:

```
var i = 1500;
var timeHandler;
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;

function timer() {
  timeHandler = setInterval(function() {
    if (i > 0) {
      i--;
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
    }
  }, 1000);

  function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timeHandler);
  }
}
```

I would prefer a vanilla JS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<!--Stop Button-->
<button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
```

JS

```
var i = 1500;
var timeHandler;
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;

function timer() {
  timeHandler = setInterval(function() {
    if (i > 0) {
      i--;
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timeHandler);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I was having issues with encapsulation, and needed to make sure to make sure timeHandler was accesible by the clearTimeout function

Comment: Great.  If you test it out and it works, mark an answer as correct so others can see which solved your problem.